# My HDRI doesn't appear on Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, 3d-view

I added an HDRI image (or also I tried, with Jpeg) but when I apply it, it only appears a single color. I think it could be from the image, but it doesn't appear completely as it should be.
[image: screen shot of blend showing the problem with the HDR]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your texture has to be an environment texture (node) and mapped as equirectangular or mirrorball (if it looks rounded) in world settings.  [image]

check "world background" to see it in viewport (perspective view, not ortho)

Comment: This is good but of course it has changed on 2.8+, do you know how it works? Since it comes with some provided HDRs and I want to use those but can't figure out how

Comment: No real change afaik. Go in shader editor (shift+F3), change the shader type from object to world. No change in the shader itself. The provided HDRI are used in viewport, not render unless you download them manually

Comment: @Bithur doesn't work for me. My HDRI doesn't show up even in the viewport