# Enviornment texture not acting as expected

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri

Recently, I decided to get back into Blender, just as a fun hobby. After modeling some things, I tried to use an HDR image to light my scene. When I rendered the scene, the HDRi was not working properly.

[image: Rendered scene]

As you can see, all the materials render fine, but the HDRi is not working properly. Below is the HDR image I used.

[image: HDRI]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24705/my-hdri-doesnt-appear-on-cycles-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch to perspective view instead of orthographic view (Numpad-5)