# World background color/HDRI was transparent in render

Tags: hdri, visibility

I disabled world background for the camera, and made some renders. But then I decided to use HDRI and it doesn't work. It's still transparent in renders.
I see it on reflections and through the glass but cant't see it directly. (camera visibility is checked).

Relaunching Blender doesn't help.

Comment: disable film>transparent

Comment: Related: [My HDRI doesn't appear on Cycles Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24705/my-hdri-doesnt-appear-on-cycles-render)